# Emacs (AUCTex) not writing to vc.tex file when using VC bundle in LaTeX document

Tags: macos, emacs, visual-c++, auctex

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.1 for Mac OS X on Lion with the latest version of AUCTeX and the VC bundle to print version information in a footer on my LaTeX documents. The problem is that when I typeset my LaTeX document, it runs the suggested shell command through \immediate\write18{./vc} just fine, but it's not writing anything to the vc.tex file when the vc script is run. I've checked the log file every time, and the following line always appears:

runsystem(./vc)...executed safely (allowed).

I've spent the better part of a day trying to figure out why the vc.tex is not being revised, and I've narrowed it down to a problem with Emacs/AUCTeX because TeXShop seems to be doing it just fine. Alternatively, I can always run the vc script in Terminal, but I'd like to figure out why the \immediate\write{./vc} line isn't working in Emacs.

Any ideas??

Comment: try its user group auctex@gnu.org, should you get no answer here

Comment: It seems that Emacs wasn't seeing my gawk executable file (in usr/local/bin), which it needs to run vc properly, and so nothing was being written to the vc.tex file. This was fixed by pointing Emacs to the gawk file through pandoc: (setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/local/bin:" (getenv "PATH"))) (load "pandoc-mode") (add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'turn-on-pandoc) (add-hook 'pandoc-mode-hook 'pandoc-load-default-settings)